# C# - Variable does not exists in current context

Tags: c#, visual-studio, variables, scope, declare

I have a problem I can't seem to solve.

I created a class function called test and in the function I declared a variable.
On the next line I fill the function with a string.

During debugging the variable does not get declared, my variable watcher in VS tells me that the variable does not exists in the current context.

Can you all help me solve this problem ?

Here is my code:

```
public void Test()
{
    string DirectoryPath;
    DirectoryPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.InternetCache);
}
```

Comment: Please review your question. WHich is the variable that you fill with a string or whatever??? ununderestandable!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My guess is you're using a Release configuration - the optimizer may have removed the variable, as it's pointless other than for debugging. You assign it a value, but never read it. In a Debug configuration, I'd expect it to be fine (but possibly create a warning).

EDIT: Of course, this is assuming that you were *in* the `Test()` method that you couldn't see the variable. If `Test()` had already completed then Likurg's answer is probably more appropriate.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal: It *slightly* surprises me that it does so, but I see no reason it shouldn't - release builds are designed to be optimized for running, not debugging... if a variable is pointless, why do anything with it? The method call still needs to be performed, but there's no need to assign the value back to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

If i'm not mistake you want to do this

```
    public class MyTest
    {
        string DirectoryPath = "";
        public void Test()
        {
            DirectoryPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.InternetCache);
        }
        public void UseString()
        {
            //Use DirectoryPath
        }
    }
```