# Visual Studio 2010 - can't see the value of the variable while in debug

Tags: c#, visual-studio

[image]Before I used to point on the variables and they used to show their values. **strong text**ut after I installed Visual Studio 2010 full version, I can't see variables anymore.
Sometimes I would have to do something like that to see te variable:

```
String var1 = "test";
var1=var1;
```

Please note, I check variable value after it has been initialized and after the value has been assigned.

`The name 'buyCategory' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: what happens if you `CleanUp` your project and recompile it?

Comment: Change to debug compilation and disable [compiler optimisation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199204/how-can-i-disable-compiler-optimization-in-c). http://stackoverflow.com/a/10141616/284240

Comment: Show your code sample in that case.

Comment: Your screenshot contradicts your statement that the variable has been initialized / assigned to. According to your screenshot, that would only be the case after one more debugger step (F10).

Comment: @Tim Schmelter, yes! your 100% correct! Thank you! Could you post this answer? I will choose it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change to [debug compilation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wx0123s5.aspx) and [disable compiler optimisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199204/how-can-i-disable-compiler-optimization-in-c).

Comment: This works for me, does anyone know why this happens in the first place?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like your break point is on the line that inits the variable.   YOu need to execute that line ( F10 / Debug->Step Over ) before that variable will come into existence

Comment: Oh come on that is not the case. Even if compiler had not reached that particular line, it will show that variable value as null.

Comment: you missed the original screen shot

Answer (score 2):

In the screenshot, buyCategory hasn't yet been initialized *or* assigned. Press F10 and try again.

Comment: Just a screenshot; but I mentioned that I initialize the values

Comment: 'Just a screenshot'?  dude, its your question, your fricken screenshot should be ON the money to show us what the problem is :)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible you are in a different thread as the variable you are trying to see in the Locals menu.

Answer (score 0):

Open Solution Explorer  -> Right Click on Solution -> Select Properties.

After selecting Properties, you will get one Popup window. In the window change configuration Type to **Debug** and then click Ok.